# Removing nodes from a nx graph if and only if the graph remains connected?

Tags: python, performance, networkx, graph-theory

I'm trying to remove nodes from an existing nx graph G if and only if the graph remains connected. What is the most efficient way to do this?

My attempt for removing node 5 for example is:

```
node = 5

# make temporary copy
T = G.copy()

# remove node from copy
T.remove_node(node)

# replace G with T if the graph is connected
if nx.is_connected(T):
    G = T
```

I'm just hesitant about creating copies to do this since I'm iteratively removing nodes from a large graph. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the original graph is connected?  If so, then there will be faster ways to check if the new graph is connected.  Take one neighbor of the removed node.  If there is a path from it to each of the other nodes, then the graph is still connected.  This is much faster to check (using `has_path`) than to do a check for whether the entire graph is connected.

Comment: Good idea, it is guaranteed to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

You might have overlooked the single parameter available to [Graph.copy()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.copy.html) i.e. `Graph.copy(as_view = False)`. What this parameter does is provide "a copy of the original structure without requiring any memory for copying the information". You could perform the removal on that mimicked structure and upon retaining full connection, execute it on the real thing. If you're worried about the memory clog of storing two complete networks, then the use of that parameter could be your solution. If not, you'll need  to provide more  detail in your  question and  some  reproducible code.

```
import networkx as nx
import time as t

base_graph = nx.circulant_graph(n=1000, offsets=[1])
if nx.is_connected(base_graph):
    print('Graph is connected.')

node_id_to_remove = 500

start_time = t.time()
copied_real_graph = base_graph.copy(as_view=False)
print(f"Execution Time: {(t.time() - start_time)}")

start_time = t.time()
copied_view_graph = base_graph.copy(as_view=True)
print(f"Execution Time: {(t.time() - start_time)}")

-------------------
Graph is connected.
Execution Time: 0.005429983139038086
Execution Time: 0.0003299713134765625
```